# Custom UITableCell and exporting the TableCell as png file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I would like to have an app that when i enter a numerous of data in the some of the Table cells. Then all the data will be summarised at the lowest table cell. (Which i have already done that).

My question is how can i specifically export the lowest or any specific table cell into a PNG formate as an image?

I have tried using print screen but it is not that nice and varies amount devices. Is there any code that i can only export that cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Specify your index path
NSUInteger index[] = {0, 1}; // section, row
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndexes:index length:2];

// Get the cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// Render a graphics context to turn your cell into a UIImage
CGSize imageSize = cell.bounds.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
CGContextRef imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[cell.layer renderInContext:imageContext];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Save the image as PNG
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dest = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:dest atomically:YES];
```

**EDIT**

To get a more precise snapshot of the cell, you could use the contentView property of the cell, i.e.

```
[cell.contentView.layer renderInContext:imageContext];
```

Comment: After press the export button, it crashes. The image cannot be save.  It seems to be the problem of saving the image in PNG. Is there other alternatives? THanks

Comment: What error are you getting? I am not experiencing a crash. You could try: 

[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:dest atomically:YES];

But I don't think that will make a difference, and it will not preserve translucent backgrounds.

Comment: I got this report-[NSPathStore2 CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c236f0
2013-02-02 00:23:47.429 PictureList[59133:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSPathStore2 CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c236f0'

Comment: I think that will happen if you input an NSString to UIImagePNGRepresentation in stead of a UIImage. Could you double check your code, and maybe debug to see if your image variable is actually a UIImage.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. Just one more question. If i am using grouped table style, can i select only the cell without the space on both side? Many thanks